# Evolutionary advantage of a sex ratio skewed towards the female end in humanoids?

Tags: biology, evolution, fantasy-races, gender

I had an idea for a humanoid species that has a significant number more female births than male births, how would this trait have provided enough of an advantage to allow the species to survive to develop civilization?

Comment: This is an astoundingly broad question. The possibilities are truly endless.

Comment: Not only is it broad, it's also well documented.  Try this for breeding ratios, it's a bit dry. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2833377/

Comment: You may want to reword the question to something like "If there was a skewed sex ratio would X happen?" or "If there was a skewed sex ratio how would they avoid Y?", and you may want to say just how skewed it is. Otherwise, the question may be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Giter all the variations you provided are likely to end up as POB.

Comment: Fun Fact: Goats are more likely to have males rather than females (from experience).

Comment: Bees have that. Females are (infertile) workers, males are just for mating with the queen. In humanoids, everybody is fertile, so Fisher principle will kick in. Maybe you can have females be larger and healthier, while males are weaker and more likely to die as children, but are necessary for genetic diversity.

Comment: @Aify, POB is way, way, way overused.  What, exactly, do you think it means (especially when both of Giter's suggestions would have led to definable and judgeable answers)?

Comment: @JBH The first of variant has only 3 possible answers (thus saving it from being too broad), "yes", "no", and "maybe", but evidence could be provided for all three cases, thus leaving the decision of a "correct" answer to be up in the air for the OP to pick as he likes (therefore POB; all answers are equal). The second variant could work, given enough restrictions, but there must be an emphasis on the restrictions to restrict the "how" component, as without restrictions, it would be both TB and POB. Note that I said the variants are **likely** to end up as POB; I didn't say it was guaranteed.

Comment: @Aify: I don't see how that would be too opinion-based. An answer could give examples on how such a ratio already happens in nature because of some advantage it gives the critter or some biological reason why a certain ratio is too skewed to be sustainable(and thus any expected advantages are irrelevant).

Comment: @Giter which variant are you referring to?

Comment: @Aify: Each could be answered with an actual example from nature(or something close and extrapolated), or some explanation why such a skewed ratio would have  some problem that makes any advantage not worth it. So, answers would be "Yes/No, because [some example/problem]" which is certainly not an opinion.

Comment: @Giter My problem with that is, "yes, because X" versus "No, because Y" **could both be equally valid** - which leaves it POB up to OP to decide.

Comment: @Aify: The 'opinion-based' close vote is used if the question causes answers based primarily on opinion. The 'too-broad' close vote is used if the question causes more than one answer to be valid. If several answers are equally valid, then even if an opinion is needed to choose one, as long as the answers themselves aren't opinions then the question is too broad but not opinion-based.

Comment: Why of why is it so common to have more women than men and so rare to have more men than women? Consolation link: [*Sexmission*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexmission), a hilarious 1984 Polish take on the subject. (Well, I saw it at that time and I remember it fondly.)

Comment: @Giter, part of the discussion between Aify and I (and the rest of this site) is that the POB reason listed in the VTC dialog is NOT APPLICABLE to creative sites where it is often impossible to answer definitively.  We've had to change the perspective (you can find the various Meta discussions).  Basically, POB is when the OP fails to provide enough limiting information to justify the selection of a best answer.  The problem with this imperfect solution is that "enough limiting information" is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 5):

The evolution of sexual reproduction comes at a significant cost to a species because males cannot produce offspring. Species that are all hermaphrodites are capable of producing twice as many progeny each generation as species with an equal sex ratio. This is called the [two-fold cost of sex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_sexual_reproduction#Population_expansion_cost_of_sex). Sexual reproduction evolved and persists however because species that routinely recombine their genes are, to put it simply, better at evolution.

So following this line of thought, you need at least some males in order to have a sexually reproducing species. But why does the cost have to be “two-fold”? Why should half the species’ population be male when a much smaller proportion of males could serve the needs of the species. In fact, a lower ratio of males would be evolutionarily optimal from the perspective of the species but it won’t occur because evolutionary game theory occurs at the individual level. It turns out that a 50-50 male/female ratio is an [evolutionary stable strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy) according to [Fisher’s principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_principle). Essentially, if a population has a skewed sex-ratio, then it becomes evolutionarily advantageous for individuals to produce offspring of the minor sex as they will have better reproductive opportunities. Thus the system is always self-correcting towards the evolutionarily stable strategy of 50-50 male/female.

So, having more females than males actually is an evolutionarily favorable strategy as it increases the total potential progeny of the species, but it can never persist stably because evolution is always pushing against it. If you want a population like this you need to break Fisher’s principle in some way. Check out the parasitic/symbiotic bacteria [Wolbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia) that change the sex of infected insects and the sex of their progeny to suit their own needs.

Comment: I cant remember where, but there are suggestions that there are a few more males born than females. But eventually more females are left to breed. This is fairly obvious if you look at mortality rates between males and females by age. At puberty theres a huge spike in male mortality, this reduces the total amount of men to women ratio, which is actually very healthy as there are less men necessary for a healthy genepool while enough women are necessary because the time and dangers of pregnancy and nurturing.

Comment: @Demigan: For humans, the [sex ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sex_ratio) at birth is about 106 boys to 100 girls (between 105 and 107, depending on sources). Boys are somewhat more fragile, so the sex ratio becomes very close to 1:1 in the general population.